# Разборка строки JSON

Tags: java, json

```
{"firstName":"***","lastName":"***","nickName":"***","email":"***","password":"***","customerType":"***","formId":"***"}
```

1. При работе со строками, возможно ли достать по Key сам Value данной строки JSON ?
2. Есть ли метод удалить из строки formId ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. При работе со строками, возможно ли достать по Key сам Value данной строки JSON ?

Можно

В своих проектах для работы с JSON использую библиотеку [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java).

```
/* Создаём JSON-объект из указанной строки */
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("{\"firstName\":\"***\",\"lastName\":\"***\",\"nickName\":\"***\",\"email\":\"***\",\"password\":\"***\",\"customerType\":\"***\",\"formId\":\"***\"}");
String firstName = jObj.getString("firstName"); // Извлекаем значение типа String по указанному ключу.
```

> 2. Есть ли метод удалить из строки formId ?

Аналогично тому, что выше:

```
jObj.remove("formId"); // Удаляем элемент по указанному ключу.
```

Другие методы для работы с JSON вы так же можете посмотреть в репозитории библиотеки